# Can you apply product rule to arg of a bra-ket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, vectors, differentiation

I found the following expression in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3359):

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\arg\langle\phi_+|\dot{\phi_-}\rangle
$$

where the $\arg$ term is the argument of the complex number given by inner product between two eigenstates $\phi_+$ and $\phi_-$, and the dot indicates a time-derivative.

Does the product rule apply in the usual sense in this case? i.e., does the following hold? If not, why?

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\arg\langle\phi_+|\dot{\phi_-}\rangle = \arg\langle\dot\phi_+|\dot{\phi_-}\rangle + \arg\langle\phi_+|\ddot{\phi_-}\rangle
$$
I could not find much about $\arg$ terms in quantum mechanics and bra-ket literature, and so would appreciate any help you might have to offer.

Comment: @AaronStevens thanks for the comment, but would you mind clarifying what you meant by “they” (the bra-ket without arg?) and “normal vectors” (orthogonal)?

Comment: @AaronStevens thank you for clarifying. Yes, that is how I interpreted it, and that means that the time derivative is a kind of rate of change of angle. However, I am trying to make more sense of this interesting notation by wondering whether the product rule can be applied the way I wondered about in my question.

Comment: Correction: taking the magnitude of the dot product is one way to interpret it. The way I think is natural to the paper is to take the fact that the dot product is a complex number, making the arg the argument of the resulting complex number.

Comment: You should definitely make the edit in the question then.

Comment: I just went ahead and edited it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it definitely doesn't work that way. Take $z\equiv \langle \phi_+ |\dot{\phi}_-\rangle$. It is true you can use the product rule on derivatives of $z$. But $Arg$ is a nontrivial function and you need to use a chain rule.

$$z=|z|e^{iArg (z)}$$
$$\log z = \log |z|+iArg(z)$$
where $Arg$ is only defined up to an integer times $2\pi$ but it won't matter since we're taking a derivative,
$$\frac{d}{dt}Arg(z)=\frac{d}{dt}\text{Im}\log z=\text{Im}\frac{\dot{z}}{z}$$
So the product rule appears in $\dot{z}$ but otherwise it looks nothing like it.